# How to programmatically create a custom cursor similar to the cursor in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created this component for Android TV, but it has a drawback in control, I need my own cursor, like in the browser.

this is just an example so I can test: control it using the WASD key and so that when you press Enter it accesses the element where the cursor is located.

my code:

```
const step = 10
export default function Dpad() {
  const [mouse, setMouse] = useState({ x: 300, y: 300 })
  const mousePosRef = useRef(mouse)

  const getElement = useCallback(() => {
    let element = document.elementFromPoint(
      mousePosRef.current.x,
      mousePosRef.current.y
    )
    console.log(element)
  }, [])

  const mouseMove = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      switch (e.key) {
        case "w":
          setMouse((prev) => {
            return { y: prev.y - 1 - step, x: prev.x }
          })
          break

        case "d":
          setMouse((prev) => {
            return { y: prev.y, x: prev.x + 1 + step }
          })
          break

        case "a":
          setMouse((prev) => {
            return { y: prev.y, x: prev.x - 1 - step }
          })
          break

        case "s":
          setMouse((prev) => {
            return { y: prev.y + 1 + step, x: prev.x }
          })
          break

        case "Enter":
          console.log("Click")
          getElement()
          break

        default:
          break
      }
    },
    [getElement]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    mousePosRef.current = mouse
  }, [mouse])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", mouseMove, true)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", mouseMove)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div
      tabIndex={0}
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        pointerEvents: "none",
        zIndex: 999999,
        background: "red",
        width: "30px",
        height: "30px",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        left: mouse.x,
        top: mouse.y,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Need an exact element: how to work around the problem with elementFromPoint and only return the immediate element under the cursor?. Can this be implemented and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `elementFromPoint` method along with a recursive approach

```
const getElement = useCallback(() => {
  let targetElement = document.elementFromPoint(
    mousePosRef.current.x,
    mousePosRef.current.y
  );

  // Traverse up the DOM tree until we find the actual target element
  while (targetElement && targetElement.tagName !== "BODY") {
    const rect = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (
      mousePosRef.current.x >= rect.left &&
      mousePosRef.current.x <= rect.right &&
      mousePosRef.current.y >= rect.top &&
      mousePosRef.current.y <= rect.bottom
    ) {
      console.log("Target Element:", targetElement);
      return;
    }
    targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
  }
}, []);
```